# Read a file that's contantly updated in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository, inputstream

I'm trying to develop a spring boot application that will run and write a .json file in Resources periodically and then read those values and insert them in a jparepository so I can access them from the database. I have no problem writing to the file periodically but I am only able to read the file when the code is executed. I tried to use @Scheduled, it works in the sense that runs every 90 seconds but it will only give me the same values although the .json file has being updated. I want to update the database with the data of the .json file that updates constantly.

Here is my code:

Main application
`

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.Services.MasterService;
import com.example.demo.model.Master;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

@Data
class MasterList {
    List<Master> masterList;
}

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ReadAndWriteJsonApplication {
    @Autowired
    private MasterService masterService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReadAndWriteJsonApplication.class, args);
        TimerTaskUtil util = new TimerTaskUtil();
        util.callTimerTask();

    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=90000)

    public void readFile() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        TypeReference<List<Master>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Master>>(){};

        InputStream inputStream = MasterList.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/file.json");


        try {

            List<Master> users = mapper.readValue(inputStream,typeReference);
            System.out.println("users "+users);
            
                masterService.save(users);
           
            System.out.println("Saved");


        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Unable to save users: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

`Repository`

```
package com.example.demo.Repository;


import com.example.demo.model.Master;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MasterRepository extends CrudRepository<Master, Long> {


}
```

`MasterService Class.`

```
package com.example.demo.Services;

import com.example.demo.Repository.MasterRepository;
import com.example.demo.model.Master;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;


@Service
public class MasterService {
    @Autowired
    private MasterRepository masterRepository;

    public MasterService(MasterRepository masterRepository) {

        this.masterRepository = masterRepository;
    }

    public Iterable<Master> list() {
        return masterRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Master save(Master  master){
        return masterRepository.save(master);
    }

    public Iterable<Master> save(List<Master> masters) {
        return masterRepository.saveAll(masters);
    }
}
```

`Any help is appreciated and sorry for my english, it is my second language.

I tried to read the file on a separated class but i get the following error `Cannot invoke "com.example.demo.Services.MasterService.save(java.util.List)" because "com.example.demo.MyRunner.masterService" is null`.

It seems that the reason why it wont update is because the file is consider as a static resource, so any update will be ignored unlease I start the API again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not best practice to use an `@Autowired` annotation on a field.  Instead, make your class extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`.  Now, create a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`.  Start your application logic from there.